# Flutter: CustomAppBar and automaticallyImplyLeading.. How to?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, custom-controls, appbar

My custom appbar does not behave the same as the flutter stock AppBar with respect to backward navigation.

Is there an easy way to give my custom appbar this functionality? ...is 'automaticallyImplyLeading' involved?

FYI, I will not be offended if you explain it to me like I'm 6 years old; I am quite new to coding. ..sock puppets and code snippets welcome.

My current code (`gradient-app-bar.dart` & `post_detail.dart`):

```
// MY CUSTOM APPBAR (GRADIENT-APP-BAR.DART) //
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
    final double _preferredHeight = 200.0;
    final String bizName;
    final String streetAddress;
    final String cityStateZip;
    final String phoneNumber;
    // final String bizHours;
    final String masterList;
    final Color gradientBegin, gradientEnd;

    GradientAppBar({
            this.bizName,
            this.streetAddress,
            this.cityStateZip,
            this.phoneNumber,
            // this.bizHours,
            this.masterList,
            this.gradientBegin,
            this.gradientEnd,
            // List<Widget> actions,
        }):
        assert(bizName != null),
        assert(streetAddress != null),
        assert(cityStateZip != null),
        assert(phoneNumber != null),
        // assert(bizHours != null),
        assert(masterList != null),
        assert(gradientBegin != null),
        assert(gradientEnd != null);


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            height: _preferredHeight,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: < Color > [
                        gradientBegin,
                        gradientEnd
                    ]
                )
            ),

            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                    Text(bizName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            letterSpacing: 5.0,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                        )
                    ),
                    Text(streetAddress,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            letterSpacing: 2.0,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                        )
                    ),
                    Text(cityStateZip,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            letterSpacing: 2.0,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                        )
                    ),
                    Text(phoneNumber,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            letterSpacing: 2.0,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                        )
                    ),
                    // Text(bizHours,
                    //   style: TextStyle(
                    //     color:Colors.white,
                    //     letterSpacing: 5.0,
                    //     fontSize: 20.0,
                    //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                    //   )
                    // ),
                    Text(masterList,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            letterSpacing: 5.0,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                        )
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        );
    }

    @override
    Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(_preferredHeight);
}


// MY CUSTOM APPBAR IMPLEMENTED (POST_DETAIL.DART) //

import 'package:appvervemenu/gradient-app-bar.dart';
import 'package:appvervemenu/post_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PostDetail extends StatelessWidget {
    final Post post;

    PostDetail({
        @required this.post
    });

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: GradientAppBar(
                bizName: "BIZNAME",
                streetAddress: "STREETADDRESS",
                cityStateZip: "CITYSTATEZIP",
                phoneNumber: "BIZPHONE",
                masterList: "\n\nMASTERLIST",
                gradientBegin: Color(0xFFB71C1C),
                gradientEnd: Color(0xFFB71C1C),
            ),

            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Column(
                            children: < Widget > [
                                Card(
                                    child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: < Widget > [
                                            ListTile(
                                                title: Text(post.title),
                                                // subtitle: Text(post.title),
                                            ),
                                            ListTile(
                                                title: Text("Featuring"),
                                                subtitle: Text(post.body),
                                            ),
                                            ListTile(
                                                // title: Text("ID"),
                                                subtitle: Text("${post.id}"),
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need a custom AppBar? who not simply customise the built in AppBar?

Comment: hey where were you 3 days ago when i posted that very question? ..lol. anyway, the solution i was advised to try was a custom appbar.. so thats what i tried.. and here we are. i would be thrilled if you could help me customize the built in appbar so that i can fit 5 rows of text and a logo. either solution you can help me with would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you look at the source code of AppBar, It builds a leading widget internally by checking if there is a drawer then show the menu icon or if the navigator can be popped the show a back button.